# How do magnitude, accuracy, and proximity relate to each other with regards to CLLocationAccuracy

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I am wondering if the magnitude value of a `CLLocationAccuracy` object represents distance in meters. It is described like this in `Xcode` docs:

> Description: The magnitude of this value. //this value being accuracy
>   value?
>
> For any value x, x.magnitude.sign is .plus. If x is not NaN,
>   x.magnitude is the absolute value of x. The global abs(*:) function
>   provides more familiar syntax when you need to find an absolute value.
>   In addition, because abs(*:) always returns a value of the same type,
>   even in a generic context, using the function instead of the magnitude
>   property is encouraged.
>
> Listing 1
>   let targetDistance: Double = 5.25
>   let throwDistance: Double = 5.5
>
> let margin = targetDistance - throwDistance // margin == -0.25 //
>   margin.magnitude == 0.25
>
> // Use 'abs(_:)' instead of 'magnitude' print("Missed the target by
>   (abs(margin)) meters.") // Prints "Missed the target by 0.25 meters."

How does the magnitude relate to distance, if at all? I can see that it is different from the raw `proximity` value because it goes higher than 3.

For example (from console output of testing):

```
[CLBeacon (uuid:12345678-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935, major:1, minor:3, proximity:3 +/- 5.39m, rssi:-71)] //a beacon that is being ranged
major: 1
minor: 3
accuracy: 5.38695083568272

2.64546246474154 --- magnitude
```

You can see the accuracy is 5.3869... and the proximity value is 3...and magnitude is 2.6454 - how do they all relate?

Comment: `CLLocationAccuracy` is just a typedef of `Double`, so the magnitude is just the magnitude from `Double` which is the absolute value as the docs say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **accuracy value attempts to estimate the distance form the beacon in meters**.  This was confirmed in a private Apple forum several years ago by an Apple support engineer, and it is consistent with my testing.  The docs for the property say is is the *"one sigma horizontal accuracy in meters where the measuring device's location is referenced at the beaconing device."*  This simply means that the best guess of iOS is that your distance from the beacon is about the accuracy value in meters.

The **proximity value is simply an enumeration** that represents the following values and their raw integer equivalents:

```
unknown      0
immediate    1
near         2
far          3
```

These are basically distance "buckets" derived from the accuracy field.  An accuracy of 0-0.5 will give you an immediate proximity.  An accuracy value of 0.5-3 meters will give you a near proximity and an accuracy value > 3 will give you far.  Unknown is returned if the accuracy cannot be computed (it typically returns -1 in this case.)

The documentation shown in the question for "magnitude" is about a mathematical function related to absolute value.  It has nothing to do with beacons and is not related to accuracy and proximity of a CLBeacon.

Comment: Outstanding answer, as always. Whenever I see a well written, informative answer about iBeacons, it's a fair bet you are the author. :) (Voted.)

Comment: It's awful that for beacon readings, accuracy actually means distance, and for the location manager, the accuracy reading is a "circle of confusion" (The radius of of a circle that describes the possible area where the reading may actually be located, after allowing for error.)

Answer (score 0):

- Accuracy is simply giving you a value on how accurate the data is.

  At least for CLLocation we use different params such as  kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer, among others.  Docs at: [CLLocation.desiredAccuracy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy)
- Proximity is an obvious one, how close you are to the beacon (proximity :3 +/- 5.39m) between 3 to 5.4 meters.
- Magnitude in general terms is simply an absolute value, but unsure how it fits into your problem... pretty sure its useless unless someone can correct me.